# Wordpress define('COOKIE_DOMAIN',false) implications

Tags: php, wordpress, cookies

I have a Wordpress multisite which uses two different domains e.g:

- www.test.com - primary site
- www.example.com

In order to get the login to work on the non primary site I have had to add the following line in my wp-config.php file

```
define('COOKIE_DOMAIN',false);
```

This allows any of the WordPress Domains to set the Cookie and in turn allows a user to login on the secondary site. My question is what are the security implications to effectively wildcarding the Cookie domain?

Answer (score -1):

Wildcarding the Cookie domain by setting COOKIE_DOMAIN to false in a WordPress multisite environment has security implications that are important to consider.

```
Security Implications:
```

- Increased Attack Surface:
- Session fixation:
- Cross-Site Scripting (XSS) Risks:
- Cookie Hijacking:

If an attacker gains access to the cookies, they could impersonate a user on any subdomain covered by the wildcard.

```
Secure Cookies:
```

Set the secure and httponly flags on cookies to enhance their security. The secure flag ensures cookies are only sent over secure (HTTPS) connections, and the httponly flag prevents client-side scripts from accessing the cookie.

```
define('COOKIE_DOMAIN', false);
define('COOKIEPATH', '/');
define('SITECOOKIEPATH', '/');
define('ADMIN_COOKIE_PATH', '/');
define('SECURE_AUTH_COOKIE', 'secure_auth');
define('LOGGED_IN_COOKIE', 'logged_in');
define('TEST_COOKIE', 'test_cookie');
define('COOKIEHASH', '');
```